# CodeIgniter does not load the functions from my controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I started with CodeIgniter today, and I’m following the beginner tutorial from phpacademy.
Right now I got an odd problem, I got the following very simple controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit("No direct script access allowed");

 class Site extends CI_Controller {
 public function index()
 {
 }

 public function home()
 {
     $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
 }

 function about()
 {
     $data['title'] = "About!";
     $this->load->view("view_about", $data);
 }

 function test()
 {
     echo "test";
 }
}
```

It always loads the index function fine. When I test it, it echoes whatever I want it to echo. But when I call the other functions nothing happen.

I didn’t set up my .htacces yet, but when I visit the following address:
localhost:8899/index.php/site/home

it doesn’t load the home function. same goes for the other function (“about” and “test”);

When I call one of the functions (“home”, “about” and “test”) from within the index() function it does call it how it should:

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
{
    $this->home();
}

public function home()
{
    $this->load->view("view_home", $data);
}
```

I’m not sure what is going wrong here. Hopefully, someone can guide me in the right direction!

My Routes:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit("No direct script access allowed");

$route['default_controller'] = "site";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

Comment: Have you set the base_url in your config.php ? Does both `localhost:8899/index.php` and `localhost:8899/index.php/site/index` work for loading your index method? It may also be worthwhile posting the contents of your routes.php file.

Comment: Yes. `localhost:8899/index.php/site/index` also loads my index method just fine

Comment: oh, and i haven't setup my `BASE_URL`. i read CI will auto-detect te base url since 2.0

Comment: Try setting it to `http://localhost:8899/index.php/` and see if it makes a difference. If not, add the contents of your routes.php to your question, as it most likely needs changing.

Comment: added the routes to my question aswell

Comment: Well, your routes.php looks fine. What exactly is happening when you go to `localhost:8899/index.php/site/about` ? Do you get a white screen? If you add an echo 'test'; to your `about` method, does it not get displayed?

Comment: i just get the index method thats it.

Comment: @Jeemusu Ok i fixed the issue. For some reason In my `config.php` i had `$config['uri_protocol']= 'QUERY_STRING'`. That was the problem all along. I'm not quite sure why it was not on `AUTO` as it should

Thanks for your time and help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If somebody came across this since no solutions above worked, ok you can try these steps where i got the thing worked (local with xampp):

1. Change the `base_url` in `config.php` into `http://localhost/application-name/`
2. Empty the `index_page` (the default value should be `index.php`)
3. Go to root folder of your application and check that `index.php` is there
4. Make `.htaccess` file in there and write into that these:

   ```
    RewriteEngine  On
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
    RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
    RewriteRule  ^(.*)$  index.php/$1  [L]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

i would make sure the controller class has a constructor to load the base codeigniter base classes.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

in each controller class tells your class to use the code igniter system.  if this is not present it won't know to how to load these functions.

Just to be clear, make sure it calls the other methods by url/site/about  etc...
Also, have you got php errors displaying on you development server?